# How to use first 50 data from hashmap data

Tags: java, android, hashmap, treemap

I have data on the hashmap, and the data in the hashmap changes every second. Hashmap size will 347 at times and 197 at other times. such as below:

```
2022-12-25 16:48:27.140 8081-8081/com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial D/ContentValues: rightdatadict size(): 347
2022-12-25 16:48:28.115 8081-8081/com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial D/ContentValues: rightdatadict size(): 218
2022-12-25 16:48:29.231 8081-8081/com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial D/ContentValues: rightdatadict size(): 194
```

What if I only want to get the first 50 items in the `HashMap` every second?

I try use this code but it does not work:

```java
Map<String,Object> rightDataDict = new TreeMap<>();
Date date = new Date();
rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)),Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));
right_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(rightDataDict.size()==50){
                    rightDataDict.clear();
                }
            }
        });
    }
},1000, 1000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first 50 items"?  HashMaps do not have an innate ordering.

Comment: I just want get 50 data each seconds. so the results should be 2022-12-25 16:48:27.140 8081-8081/com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial D/ContentValues: rightdatadict size(): 50, 2022-12-25 16:48:28.115 8081-8081/com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial D/ContentValues: rightdatadict size(): 50

Comment: If you want to preserve the order of the first 50 values dropped in a map, you can go for LinkedHashMap... Also,You could have a counter variable to keep track of the number of items picked from the map..Once the counter reaches 50 you can break it...

Comment: So you want them in order of date?  You might be better to use a `TreeMap<Instant, String>` instead of a `HashMap`.  A `HashMap` does not have a defined order.

Comment: The given information is incomplete, please add more details